¿Como se pone la barra inclinada “\“ como texto en C++?
quería saber como se pone como texto la barra inclinada “\“ en C++, en el caso de que se pueda. Gracias.

Supongo que te refieres en cadenas, escápala usando otra barra inversa: std::cout<<"Hola\\mundo";

Funciona! Muchísimas gracias.
